# Display several images using CImg class on C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, cimg

How can one display several images of cards (52 cards)  into a 'grid'?
I am trying to create four piles in the upper left corner, four piles in the upper right corner, eight piles that make up the main table for my game with the use of `CImg` class.

Comment: CImg of Template Image processing toolkit?

Comment: Visual C++ has already built in functions for image display like `CBitmap` and `CImage`. If those are not enough you can integrate CxImage, a third party image library. It is the first time I hear about CImg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can use `append()` like this:

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {
   // Load up all images into CImg structures
   CImg<unsigned char> c7("7.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> c9("9.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> c4("4.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> cjack("jack.png");

   // Declare output and intermediate variables
   CImg<unsigned char> row0,row1,grid;

   // Append horizontally into a row, you could append many - you are not restricted to 2
   row0 = c7.append(cjack,'x');

   // Append horizontally into a row
   row1 = c4.append(c9,'x');

   // Append vertically into a column
   grid = row0.append(row1,'y');

   grid.display();
}
```

[image]

---

**Original Answer**

The easiest way is probably to *append* images like this:

```
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {
   CImg<unsigned char> c7("7.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> c9("9.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> cjack("jack.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> row;
   row = c7.append(cjack,'y').append(c9,'y');
   row.display();
}
```

which gives this:

[image]

If you change the `'y'` axis parameter for `append()` to `'x'` they will append side-by-side:

```
   CImg<unsigned char> col;
   col = c7.append(cjack,'x').append(c9,'x');
   col.display();
```

[image]

So, you should be able to see how to make a grid now.

Answer (score 0):

CImg itself has a very basic ability to display images in windows. All you can do is display multiple images, aligning them along one of the axes using the **CImgDisplay** struct. See the documentation for [CImgDisplay::display() method](http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImgDisplay.html#a616d2352d40e76ee7bdfb77e01e1cd87). You can play with the 4 available axes and see if that fits your needs.

If that's not enough for you, you have to use some external library for display.