# add background image to this code instead black?

Tags: image, background, cimg

I see this code and need add a image of background

like this
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xu6m.jpg)

how I could do this add a background instead black background

please help me

I get this code from another question but I dont know how change the background

[Create video from array of pixel values in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24228728/create-video-from-array-of-pixel-values-in-c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
   const unsigned int width=1024;
   const unsigned int height=768;

   // Basic frame we will draw in
   CImg<unsigned char> image(width,height,1,3);

   unsigned char magenta[] = {255,0,255};

   // We are going to output 300 frames of 1024x768 RGB raw video
   // ... making a 10s long video at 30fps
   int radius=100;
   int cx=100;
   int cy=100;
   for(int frame=0;frame<300;frame++){
      // Start with black - it shows fewer stains ;-)
      image.fill(0);
      image.draw_circle(cx,cy,radius,magenta);

      // Move and re-colour circle
      cx+=2; cy++; if(magenta[1]!=255){magenta[1]++;}

      // Output to ffmpeg to make video, in planar GBR format
      // i.e. run program like this
      // ./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
      char* s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+(width*height));   // Get start of G plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+2*(width*height));       // Get start of B plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data());                        // Get start of R plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
   }
}
```

I compile using this

```
./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
```

Comment: This answer shows how to load an image https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780732/2836621 so load your image like that. Then instead of filling an empty canvas with black at the start of each frame, take a copy of your background image and draw on the copy and save it. What operating system are you using?

Comment: ubuntu linux os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is load the background image at the start and then make a copy of it to draw on at each iterations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main()
{
   // Background frame we will draw 
   CImg<unsigned char> bg("background.jpg");
   bg.resize(1024,768);
   int width=bg.width();
   int height=bg.height();

   unsigned char magenta[] = {255,0,255};

   // We are going to output 300 frames of RGB raw video
   // ... making a 10s long video at 30fps
   int radius=100;
   int cx=100;
   int cy=100;
   for(int frame=0;frame<300;frame++){
      // Take copy of background image
      CImg<unsigned char> image(bg,false);

      image.draw_circle(cx,cy,radius,magenta);

      // Move and re-colour circle
      cx+=2; cy++; if(magenta[1]!=255){magenta[1]++;}

      // Output to ffmpeg to make video, in planar GBR format
      // i.e. run program like this
      // ./main | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gbrp -video_size 1024x768 -i - -c:v h264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mov
      char* s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+(width*height));   // Get start of G plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data()+2*(width*height));       // Get start of B plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
      s=reinterpret_cast<char*>(image.data());                        // Get start of R plane
      std::cout.write(s,width*height);                                // Output it
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The animated GIF above is not smooth because I reduced the framerate just to fit in StackOverflow's 2MB filesize limit. The real one is smooth.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your project!